# How to get the Tag value of sprite at runtime

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I am having 20 sprites.All 20 sprites are added in MutableArray.when I touch any one of the sprite among the 20.I want the tag value of touched sprite.

Help me with code.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Register touches. Use functions:

   ```
   -(id) init{
   if( (self=[super init])){
       self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
       /* to do */
   }}

   - (void) registerWithTouchDispatcher{
   /* to do */}

   - (BOOL) containsTouchLocation:(UITouch *)touch
   {
       return YES;
   }
   ```
2. Catch and analyze touch on sprite in function

   ```
   - (BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {

   //e.g. mArrSprites - your NSMutableArray with 20 sprites

       for(CCSprite * sprite in mArrSprites){
           if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, location)){ //check contains sprite rect your touch
               int tag = sprite.tag;     //GET tag of sprite
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I am getting the exception while running after used your code."Instance method-TouchDispatcher not found(return type defaults to id)".

Answer (score 0):

That should be fairly simple. As you don't provide any code, I'll pretend it looks something like this.

```
for (CCSprite *aSprite in arrayOfSprites){
    if ([self screenPosition:touchPosition intersectedWithSprite: aSprite]){
        NSInteger tagForSprite = aSprite.tag; // do what you want with this value
    }
}
```

touchPositionIntersectedWithSprite being a method checking the actual collision and returning a BOOL...

Comment: At what point is it not working? Are the methods called when you expect them to? Does the sprites have a tag property set when being created, is the method checking the collision doing the right thing (you have to implement this yourself)? Is it getting the right data?

Comment: getting the exception for intersectedWithSprite "Method not found"

Comment: You have to create that method yourself depending on how you'd like to handle the detection. `-(BOOL) screenPosition:(ccp)position intersectedWithSprite:(CCSprite *) theSprite` You then have to use for instance CGRectContainsPoint (like @gaRik suggested) to decide whether to return YES or NO...